# Boost converter output consuming battery - will a blocking diode be of use?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, boost, step-up

I'm using a CC/CV boost converter to charge a lithium-ion battery via a USB-C PD circuit.

The issue I am having is the boost converter is consuming power from the battery connected to the output when the boost converter is not being used. I forgot exactly how much current it's consuming but I want to say it's around 20 mA. The boost converter has LM25965 and XL6019 ICs.

Is it possible to put a Schottky blocking diode on the output and adjust the voltage output to negate the voltage drop. Will that interfere with the CC/CV functionality?

I know I could put a switch on the output and when charging just switch it on but I would rather not do that in this situation.

If anyone has any other relatively simple ideas, please let me know

Do not all boost converters have this issue correct? I've used cc/cv boost converters in the past to charge batteries and don't remember having this issue.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: _Edit your question_ to include a schematic.  Try to show just the converter section in question.  It's all in the details, not just the chip used.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to put a Schottky blocking diode on the output and adjust the voltage output to negate the voltage drop.

Yes.

> Will that interfere with the CC/CV functionality?

If the CV setting is properly adjusted, no.

> Do not all boost converters have this issue?

No.

Comment: Thanks. I assumed a Schottky diode wouldn't interfere with the Cc/Cv functionality. I'm away from home at the moment and don't have any of my supplies with me and wanted to verify before ordering some diodes. I really appreciate your help. Thanks again!

Comment: (I built some 7s ~26v 10ah lithium battery packs out of 28- 18650's for my brother's furniture that has built in electric recliners, so he doesn't have to have power cords running across the floor in order to plug them in. I added USB-C 20v 5a PD triggers to them for easy charging.)